# Using javascript .click inside a partial rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, partial, renderpartial

I have a javascript click function that is called every time my textbox gets clicked on, however for some reason it only works if the textbox is inside the main page, when I move the textbox into the partial I render nothing happens when I click on it.  Does anyone know how to make a click event work inside a partial?

My users.js.coffee file

```
$ ->
  $("form[data-update-target]").live "ajax:success", (evt, data) ->
    target = $(this).data("update-target")
  $("#" + target).html data

  $("input.submit").click ->
    $(this).parent().submit()
    true

  $("#datepicker").click ->
    alert "hello world"
```

The new page for users

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'users', :action => 'preview'}, :remote => true, :'data-update-target' => 'update-container') do %>
  <%= radio_button_tag(:page_type, 'event', false, :class => 'submit') %>
  <%= label_tag(:page_type, "Event") %>
  <br/>
<% end %>
<div id="update-container">
</div>
```

The users controller

```
def preview
  if params[:page_type] == "event"
    @event = Event.new
    render :partial => 'event', :object => @event
  end
end
```

The events partial called _event.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start %>
    <input id="datepicker" type="text" value="" name="event_start">
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

generated html

```
<body>
<p id="notice"></p>
<p id="alert"></p>
  <h1>New page</h1>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/preview" data-remote="true" data-update-target="update-container" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="iIodOQohxJgk1P5ZmFrbgw4W/h4cq45LBxGN3xjyREk=" /></div>

<input class="submit" id="page_type_event" name="page_type" type="radio" value="event" />
<label for="page_type">Event</label>
<br/>
</form><div id="update-container">
</div>
<input id="datepicker" type="text" value="" name="event_start">

<a href="/users">Back</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show the generated js and html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: there is no input with submit class. You either want to add the submit class to the proper input element or change the selector to something like `$('input[type=submit]')`

On the other hand, if I use a class only for js behaviour, I usually prepend `js-` to the name, so the designer knows that he should not remove it (or use it for styling).

But, if the problem is because the datepicker is not rendered when the page is loaded (added later with javascript, for example), you need to declare the callback differently.

Choose a datepicker's parent that is present since the first time the page is rendered (in case there is none, you can use `document`). In this case, the parent is `div#update-container`:

```
$("#update_-container").on 'click', '#datepicker', (evt) ->
    # code here....
```

For more info, look at the [official jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Sorry I'm not positive on what you mean, however I assume you're referring to $("input.submit") which actually seems to work fine.  My issue is the function below that where $("datepicker").click refuses to execute

Comment: Can you paste the generated html, please?

Comment: I updated the question with the generated html, it's interesting however since the html for the partial is never really generated or at least displayed in the source when it's rendered, which I think why .click isn't working but I'm not sure how to fix it.  It's either something to do with the render function in rails or ajax I think.

Comment: If it's not rendered when the page is loaded, then the event will not get the callback.

Comment: how would I fix it so it renders correctly?  As I am able to see the partial as well as press the submit button/interact with the partial and have it work fine, minus the fact that it doesn't actually exist in the source code.

Comment: Can you update the question with how your form works? Right now I'm assuming the partial is rendered when the form is submitted, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: when a user selects a radio button the partial is rendered within the update-container div.  From there you can enter information inside the partial and press the submit button inside to submit the data.

Comment: thanks, the fix works great.  Takes a little bit to load before it appears unfortunately but that's probably another issue.  Thanks